# include external js file is not working on tablet only

Tags: javascript, tablet

i created a web page which uses external js file, the web page cannot include the external js file only when i use a tablet , it works very well on pc and on mobile, only in tablets it doesn't see any functions inside the external file

i tried to write the jquery functions inside the HTML file it works well, i tried the defer attribute but it also doesn't work

`<script src="confirmvisit.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>`

when i call any function from the external file, it gives me an error that function name is not defined, i can now copy and past all the js file inside the HTML itself, but i need to make it from external file

Comment: did you check the network tab while opening on tablet mode?

Comment: i am working online , the page is already loaded on my host , so i tried it from the tablet itself not tablet mode

Comment: Can i see the code? maybe a jsfiddle?

Comment: i tested it on the same tablet but using firefox it works well , i think now the problem in the chrome version , what do you think